# PHP upload size not changing from 2MB in phpinfo()

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to change the PHP file upload from 2MB. I've changed the php.ini files found in `/etc/php5/apache2` and in `/etc/php5/cli` to other values, but my `phpinfo()` page shows me that the `upload_max_filesize` is still stuck on 2MB!

I've checked `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in both the php.ini files with no luck. I've restarted the Apache server multiple times and haven't seen any changes. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm completely stumped!

Comment: If you've already changed both php.ini files and restarted the server, there must be some other problems. Can you confirm that the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings only exist once in each file? PHP may take only the first setting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. They only exist once in each file. I just checked again!

Comment: The settings in `/etc/php5/cli` will make no difference here - that's for your console version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks. In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini Upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are set to 100M.

Comment: Check in your `phpinfo()` output where it is expecting to read `php.ini` from. Sometimes this is non-standard, and you could be reading a file that is not being read. Also, you are viewing phpinfo() via Apache and not the console, right?

Comment: Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. I'm viewing phpinfo() via Apache.

Comment: I just did. I got: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 523800 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
Could not startup.
This is very odd as memory_set is 128M!